# I want to display the data form two collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to display the data from two different mongoose collection.

I have two collection which is **Member** collection and **Property** collection

here is my get code

```
const Property  = require('../models/propsSchema')
const Members  = require('../models/userSchema')


router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  Members.find({})
  Property.find({})
  .exec()
  .then((props, member) => {
    console.log(props)
    console.log(member)
    res.render('index', { member : member, props : props } )    
    })
})
```

The console log result of "member" is undefined but the console log of "props" is the data of "Property". I want to fetch them both

Comment: `Promise.all(Members.find(),Property.find()).then((members, props) => ...` you know the rest

Comment: Thankyou sir ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()` function in your code

```
const Property  = require('../models/propsSchema')
const Members  = require('../models/userSchema')


router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  Promise.all([Members.find({}),
  Property.find({})])
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data[0])
    console.log(data[1])
    res.render('index', { member : data[0], props : data[1] } )    
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You save my life <3